# An acute diacritical mark not being typeset

Tags: tex-core

Why is the umlaut over the "i" typeset but not the acute over the "e" typeset?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{10.) The author of Passage 2 would most likely respond to the journalists' view in Passage 1 of the battle between the forces ``good'' and ``evil'' by}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }praising the journalists’ idealism \\
\> \textbf{b.) }mocking the journalists' na{\"i}vet{\'e} \\
\> \textbf{c.) }admiring the journalists' wit \\
\> \textbf{d.) }arguing that good and evil are not easily defined \\
\> \textbf{e.) }offering exceptions to the general rule
\end{tabbing}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Au101 To match the formatting that I have in the current file ... and many similar files that I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `\'` is a specific command of `tabbing`, like `` \` ``, these accents have to be input differently inside `tabbing`, with an `a` in between, `\a'{e}` and `` \a`{e} ``; thus

```
na\"{i}vet\a'{e}
```

Note that the syntax `na{\"i}vet{\'e}` is wrong anyway and it should be

```
na\"{i}vet\'{e}
```

Of course, using UTF-8 is simpler

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }praising the journalists’ idealism \\
\> \textbf{b.) }mocking the journalists' na\"{i}vet\a'{e} \\
\> \textbf{c.) }admiring the journalists' wit \\
\> \textbf{d.) }arguing that good and evil are not easily defined \\
\> \textbf{e.) }offering exceptions to the general rule
\end{tabbing}

\bigskip

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }praising the journalists’ idealism \\
\> \textbf{b.) }mocking the journalists' naïveté \\
\> \textbf{c.) }admiring the journalists' wit \\
\> \textbf{d.) }arguing that good and evil are not easily defined \\
\> \textbf{e.) }offering exceptions to the general rule
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You possibly want a further alignment point:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}



\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2em}\= \textbf{a.) }\= \kill
\> \textbf{a.)} \> praising the journalists’ idealism \\
\> \textbf{b.)} \> mocking the journalists' na\"{i}vet\a'{e} \\
\> \textbf{c.)} \> admiring the journalists' wit \\
\> \textbf{d.)} \> arguing that good and evil are not easily defined \\
\> \textbf{e.)} \> offering exceptions to the general rule
\end{tabbing}

\bigskip

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2em}\= \textbf{a.) }\= \kill
\> \textbf{a.)} \> praising the journalists’ idealism \\
\> \textbf{b.)} \> mocking the journalists' naïveté \\
\> \textbf{c.)} \> admiring the journalists' wit \\
\> \textbf{d.)} \> arguing that good and evil are not easily defined \\
\> \textbf{e.)} \> offering exceptions to the general rule
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Within the `tabbing` environment, you have `\a'{e}` to get the acute typeset over the "e," but in `text mode`, one only has to code \'{e}. Is that right? It seems odd that one has to code an "a" in `\a'{e}` to get the acute.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire In `tabbing`, the command `\'` means a completely different thing.

Answer (score 1):

May I humbly recommend

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[mylist,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.)}, labelindent=\parindent,
  leftmargin=3\parindent}
\setlist[mylist,2]{label=\textbf{\alph*.)}, leftmargin=0.5em}

\begin{document}

\textbf{10.) The author of Passage 2 would most likely respond to the
  journalists' view in Passage 1 of the battle between the forces ``good'' and
  ``evil'' by}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }praising the journalists’ idealism \\
\> \textbf{b.) }mocking the journalists' na{\"i}vet{\'e} \\
\> \textbf{c.) }admiring the journalists' wit \\
\> \textbf{d.) }arguing that good and evil are not easily defined \\
\> \textbf{e.) }offering exceptions to the general rule
\end{tabbing}

\begin{mylist}[start=10]
  \item \textbf{The author of Passage~2 would most likely respond to the
    journalists' view in Passage~1 of the battle between the forces ``good'' and
    ``evil'' by}
 \begin{mylist}
    \item praising the journalists' idealism
    \item mocking the journalists' naïveté
    \item admiring the journalists' wit
    \item arguing that good and evil are not easily defined
    \item offering exceptions to the general rule
  \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Wiser heads may be able to improve upon my hacks with `enumitem` but it should show you what you could be doing)